# Automatic bridging of C struct functions to Swift methods

Tags: c, swift

Is there a naming convention that will allow Swift to automatically associate C functions that act on a struct with the struct itself?

For instance, CGRect is declare as following:

```
struct CGRect {
    CGPoint origin;
    CGSize size;
};
typedef struct CG_BOXABLE CGRect CGRect;

...

CG_EXTERN CGFloat CGRectGetMinX(CGRect rect)
    CG_AVAILABLE_STARTING(10.0, 2.0);
```

But I can write Swift code like this:

```
let rect = CGRect()
let minX = rect.minX
```

I've attempted to copy the same in the hope that I could get the same behaviour from my own C structs, but can't seem to get it to work correctly.

Is this automatic behaviour due to exactly how the struct is declared, or is it added elsewhere via extensions / some other magic?
If it's via extensions, how do you disallow the original `CGRectGetMinX` function in Swift?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swift 3 introduced the feature to import global functions as member functions, see
[SE-0044 Import as member](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0044-import-as-member.md).

Here is a simple example how you can use that for your own struct types:

```
typedef struct MyRect {
    int x;
    int y;
    int w;
    int h;
} MyRect;

// Import as computed property:
int MyRectGetMinX(MyRect rect)
__attribute__((swift_name("getter:MyRect.minX(self:)")));

// Import as method:
int MyRectArea(MyRect rect)
__attribute__((swift_name("MyRect.area(self:)")));
```

Now you can call it from Swift as

```
let rect = MyRect()
let mx = rect.minX
let ar = rect.area()
```

and using the global function fails to compile:

```
let mx = MyRectGetMinX(rect)
// Error: 'MyRectGetMinX' has been replaced by property 'MyRect.minX'

let ar = MyRectArea(rect)
// Error: 'MyRectArea' has been replaced by instance method 'MyRect.area()'
```

Comment: Great that worked, thanks.  How does that work for CGRect & other core graphics frameworks?  I can't see where those `__attribute__`'s are used.

Comment: @GScrivs: The name mapping can also be defined in "Framework.apinotes" files, e.g. in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/Headers/CoreGraphics.apinotes (but that does not contain a mapping for CGRectGetMinX). – SE-0044 also mentions an “automatic inference heuristic” that might apply here.